# Having trouble with forever loop

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n,copy,counter=0,prevcounter,prev;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n>0){
        counter = 0;
        n--;
        copy = n;
        while(copy>0){
            --copy;
            if(n%copy==0){
                counter++;}
                if(copy==0)break;    
            }
        if(counter>prevcounter){
            prevcounter = counter;
            prev = n;
        }

    }
    printf("%d",prev);
}
```

So here is my code:The problem is that this code goes to forever loop and the problem is right here

```
while(copy>0)
```

but if i change it to

```
while(copy>1)
```

It is working....I am trying to get why it is going to forever loop but i cant find the answer..I am decremending copy and when it gets 0 it should break from the loop..I even added another check

```
if(copy==0)break;
```

but still it didnt work..Any sugestions?Thanks

Comment: You use `prevcounter` before it is initialized. That means the value of `prevcounter` will be *indeterminate* (and seemingly random).

Comment: Also, if the loop enters with `copy == 1` then you do `--copy` making `copy == 0`. And you use that in a division, leading to division by zero and *undefined behavior*. I recommend you [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), as this problem should have been *very* obvious if stepping through the code in a debugger (though it is obvious even when thinking about it logically).

Comment: I think that When `if(copy==0)break;` is executed, division by 0 is performed in `if(n%copy==0){`.

Comment: The poor indentation in the `while` loop makes the code deceptive.

Comment: as the comment suggest please initialize 'prevcounter' and try

Comment: "this code goes to forever loop" but how do you know it is still looping, and not hanged by the divide by 0 error? Moving the `if(copy==0)break;` to above the attempted division would be better, but you might as well alter the loop control anyway.

Comment: It is strange to see `if(copy==0)break;` as the last statement in the `while(copy>0)` loop. You should rethink the logic of whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `%` when `copy=0` also. It is a bug leading to undefined behavior.(Divide by zero).

`prevcounter` is uninitialized.

Code will be something like this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n,copy,counter=0,prevcounter=0,prev;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n>0)
    {
        counter = 0;
        n--;
        copy = n;
        while(copy>0)
        {
            --copy;

            if(copy && n%copy==0){
                counter++;
            }

        }
        if(counter>prevcounter){
            prevcounter = counter;
            prev = n;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",prev);
}
```

You needed to consider all the values of the `copy` that may come up during execution. Here in the loop you will exclude the cases when `copy` becomes zero and `if(copy && n%copy==0)` ensures that.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the problem..I will keep that in mind about the modulo :D